# restore thunderbirds profiles

Tags: backup, thunderbird

I backed up *Profiles* folder from *Documents and settings/user/app data/thunderbird* and after windows reinstall copied it back over new Thunderbirds installation. For some reason new Thunderbird does not see it. It always prompts new profile creation window when I open it, and none of the old email boxes are shown. Maybe its because I didn't copied profiles.ini file, maybe due to some other reason. How can I fix that?

I can no longer access my old Thunderbird files.

OS Windows XP Pro
Thunderbird 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its anything like firefox, you can create a new profile using the old folder.

EDIT: The profiles .ini file tells thunderbird which profiles exist. You will need that for it to recognize its there. Alternatively, the method above should work as well, but I'm not at home to test on my computer.